# WEB api + Azure sql server + IIS deploy + NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON

Tags: azure, iis, asp.net-web-api, azure-sql-database

> I have created one WEB Api which has some logic to pull data from SQL
>   server. When i try to get simple string return from Web Api  i am
>   getting it. but when i am trying to get some data from AZURE Sql DB i
>   am getting  NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON error.

- API- WEB API
- DB :  AZURE Sql with `Authentication=Active Directory
  Integrated`

> Anyone faced this problem anytime before. Please suggest.

Comment: Azure integrated security will look for the NT  User used to  connect to the azure sql db in azure active directory. It cannot find that in your case. That's why its throwing an error.

Comment: @Avanish:  do you have any idea how we can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a Azure Active Directory token based authentication. Download samples [here](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/12/WebApiOnbehalf.Azuredb.zip) for Azure AD .Net WebApi using Azure AD “on-behalf of token” to connect to Azure SQL Database.

The zip file you will download contains an extensive README file describing the whole setup process step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All going through this question. i got resolved this problem.

In order to solve this issue.

- I created One separate App pool --> .net Clr Version4.0
- Added Identity With Custom Account
     Identity --> Custom Account
  In Custom account provided the credentials which i have access to DB.